# Deploy Springboot WAR to Tomcat 8.5 shows blank page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

I can deploy / undeploy the Springboot WAR package to Tomcat 8.5 successfully using the tomcat manager,
but when I try to open the webpage it shows only blank white page.
what do I miss?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapplication</artifactId>  
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <name>myapplication</name>
    <description>My Application</description>    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- exclude tomcat-jdbc, Spring Boot will use HikariCP automatically  -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is there any problem with the POM.xml ?

Also below is my application.properties

server.servlet.context-path=/myapplication

I've already trid to remove the context path and rebuild it again, but it still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I must append this dependency in POM.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also I must add this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Now it's working thanks.

Comment: The dependency part should not be necessary, but you wlll need SpringBootServletInitializer.